# How to debug print an object from jade

Tags: node.js, pug

How to debug print an object from jade,Like `console.log()` in javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can debug with `console.log` from `jade` like this:

```
div
- console.log(the_object_you_want_to_log)
div
```

Comment: This does not work for me. No errors, but nothing gets logged.

Comment: So nothing is getting printed to the console -- even if you were to try printing some random string, e.g., `console.log("test")`?

Comment: Correct, that's exactly what I tried, `console.log("test")`

Comment: What happens if you replace `- console.log...` with `= obj_you_want_to_log`? Another suggestion would be to try having it render to the screen, e.g., `pre #{ JSON.stringify(obj) }`. Let me know if either of those work.

Comment: @jbyrd - i had same problem "No errors, but nothing gets logged" - the solution was to make sure my "  - console.log" statement was within a JADE block, such as an exact replacement for a working "p" statement.

Comment: If someone wants to use this to print it into the browser's console it won't work because Jade is processed server side so console.log inside Jade will print into server side console not in the browser.

Comment: How do I see the full context object passed into Jade?

Answer (score 12):

This helped me! Able to see whole tree of Object in console.

Start script. from leftmost and just give space or tab according to your template before console.log.

```
script.
  console.log(!{JSON.stringify(Object)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug like this

```
div
   = your_debug_data
div
```

or formatted style like:

```
code.formattedDebug #{your_debug_data}
```